# LibGDX how to draw in absolute position

Tags: libgdx, position, draw

I have a simple game where I drive car. Car is in the center of screen. How to draw on screen objects likes throttle, steering wheel on absolute position, for example right bottom corner?

EDIT: Ok i found solution for me. I use second SpriteBatch without camera.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the gist seems to be to change your camera to a `PerspectiveCamera` and override the `Stage`'s `screenToStageCoordinates` so it calculates coordinates the right way.

Here's a more in-depth description about the process: [link](http://pixelscientists.com/wordpress/?p=13).

Comment: Ok i found solution for me. I use second SpriteBatch without camera.